# c++ could not pass argument to std::priority_queue constructor

Tags: c++, stl

everyone. For some reason I could not use this statement to initalize 
c++ priority_queue. for example:

please move the scroll bar to rightmost in order to see my comments.

```
class Compare1
{
  bool _is_reverse;
public: 
  Compare1(bool is_reverse = true)
    : _is_reverse(is_reverse)
  {}

 bool operator() (const std::shared_ptr<int> &lhs, const std::shared_ptr<int> &rhs) const
  {
    return (*lhs > *rhs);
  }
};

void test3()
{
  Compare1 tester;
  std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq(Compare1()); // THIS GIVES ME A ERROR      
   std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq(Compare1(false)); // THIS GIVES ME A ERROR TOO
  std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq1; // THIS IS FINE

  std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq2(tester); // THIS IS FINE TOO

  myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(200));
  myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(201));
  myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(202));
  myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(199));
  std::cout << "DEBUG:" << *(myq.top()) << ", " << myq.size() << std::endl;

}
```

I checked my c++-stl implementations:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
  template<typename _InputIterator>
    priority_queue(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
           const _Compare& __x = _Compare(),
           const _Sequence& __s = _Sequence())
: c(__s), comp(__x)
    {
  __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
  c.insert(c.end(), __first, __last);
  std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
}
#else
  template<typename _InputIterator>
    **priority_queue(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
           const _Compare& __x,
           const _Sequence& __s)**
: c(__s), comp(__x)
    {
  __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
  c.insert(c.end(), __first, __last);
  std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
}

  template<typename _InputIterator>
    priority_queue(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
           const _Compare& __x = _Compare(),
           _Sequence&& __s = _Sequence())
: c(std::move(__s)), comp(__x)
    {
  __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
  c.insert(c.end(), __first, __last);
  std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
}
#endif
```

**And, I think this line is prefectly valid `std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq(Compare1());`**

**BUT I got those compilation error messages:**

```
g++ -g -c -std=c++11 main.cc -o main.o
main.cc: In function ‘void test3()’:
main.cc:100:7: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘myq’, which is of non-class type ‘std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >, Compare1>(Compare1 (*)())’
   myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(200));
       ^
main.cc:101:7: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘myq’, which is of non-class type ‘std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>,     std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >, Compare1>(Compare1 (*)())’
   myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(201));
       ^
main.cc:102:7: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘myq’, which is of non-class type ‘std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >, Compare1>(Compare1 (*)())’
   myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(202));
       ^
main.cc:103:7: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘myq’, which is of non-class type ‘std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >, Compare1>(Compare1 (*)())’
   myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(199));
       ^
main.cc:104:34: error: request for member ‘top’ in ‘myq’, which is of non-class type ‘std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >, Compare1>(Compare1 (*)())’
   std::cout << "DEBUG:" << *(myq.top()) << ", " << myq.size() << std::endl;
                                  ^
main.cc:104:56: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘myq’, which is of non-class type ‘std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >, Compare1>(Compare1 (*)())’
   std::cout << "DEBUG:" << *(myq.top()) << ", " << myq.size() << std::endl;
                                                    ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

could anyone tell me what's going on in this example? thanks a lot.

BTW, I know `std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq(Compare1());` This is not a good pratices. Because `Compare1() object` will be deleted once this statement is executed. a `Compare& _x` will refer to a deleted object.

HOWEVER, the example in [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/) suggest this is valid for some reasons.

```
typedef priority_queue<int,vector<int>,mycomparison> mypq_type;
mypq_type fifth (mycomparison());
mypq_type sixth (mycomparison(true));
```

I am pretty confused at this points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have been a victim of C++'s [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Instead of doing

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq(Compare1()); 
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq(Compare1(false));
```

enclose in parentheses the constructor parameters

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq((Compare1()));
//                                                                                         ^          ^
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq((Compare1(false)));
//                                                                                         ^               ^
```

or use C++11's uniform initialization syntax

```
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq{Compare1()};
//                                                                                        ^          ^
std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>, Compare1> myq{Compare1(false)};
//                                                                                        ^               ^
```

Now how do you check for MVP errors? Lets see one of the error message:

```
main.cc:100:7: error: request for member ‘push’ in ‘myq’, which is of non-class type ‘std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >, Compare1>(Compare1 (*)())’
   myq.push(std::make_shared<int>(200));
   ^
```

The error message showed that you are accessing a `.push()` method of a *non-class type* `std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> >, Compare1>(Compare1 (*)())`. Look at its type, specifically this part

```
(Compare1 (*)())
```

The above type is a function signature, which, as what the error message has indicated, is of non-class type.

Comment: "You have been a victim of C++'s Most Vexing Parse" - We should lobby SO to start sending out T-shirts with this slogan.